# (How) Are identical flags by multiple users merged?

Tags: support, flag-weight

If two or more users flag the same post for the same reason, will these flags be merged into one? And what happens to the flag weight, e.g. will it be summed up or the maximum be applied?

Also, what happens to different flags on the same post? Does that post get an increased flag weight as in "here is definitely a problem"?

Comment: I hope all people who flagged should get +FW if it is valid, and the amount earned for FW should be based on their individual current FW.

Comment: @YOU: agreed, and that's another good question. Though I was more wondering whether duplicate flags flood the mod screen or not

Comment: More than that, I think I saw somewhere that post need 5 spam flags to be really treated as spam and removed, causing -100 reputation to the one who posted it..

Comment: @Shadow, FYI - [6](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work/58035#58035)

Comment: @YOU Yes, and yes, to the inquiries of your first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two or more people flag the same question then we see **all** the flags both on the flag summary page and when we view the flagged post.

It is useful to be able to see everyone who's flagged a post - certainly on the summary page - as it acts as a multiplier. The more people who've flagged a post the more likely it is to get closed quickly (certainly in my case anyway).

I assume (like YOU) that all those who flag a question get their flag weight adjusted when the flag is dismissed - either upwards for a valid flag, or downwards for an invalid one.

Comment: so basically I could turn this question into a [feature-request] to collect identical flags into one?

Comment: @Tobias - no. It's useful to be able to see how many people have flagged a question.

Comment: @ChrisF: that's why I thought a summed up weight would be useful as well. Or just a number how many users flagged

Comment: @Tobias All of that *already* happens. Flags are grouped by post, the position in the queue is equal to the sum of flag weights, and the total number of flags (and thus users) is indicated.

Comment: @GraceNote: thanks, in that case: rollback (about time I get that badge anyway)

Comment: Sometimes I see a comment on an answer from someone who I know is a diamond or very high rep. In those cases I don't flag since I figure it's already been flagged. Good thinking? Or I should join the flag parade?